# What happens if you do a balance transfer for more than you owe?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, balance-transfer

Say you owe $1k on credit card A. You get a new credit card, B, and ask for a balance transfer from A to B for $4k. What happens? Do you end up with a negative -$3k balance on A? Or would B typically ask A for your current balance and only do a $1k transfer?

Answer (score 3):

> Do you end up with a negative -$3k balance on A?

If you overpay, A will typically refund the money after some period of time.

> Or would B typically ask A for your current balance and only do a $1k transfer?

They likely will check. If you overpay, they may treat the excess as a cash advance and will hammer you on fees and interest.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the bank offering the balance transfer. I believe the norm is for the bank to check the balance before transferring to another bank directly. If they don't check, in my experience you'd have a credit for up to 3 months, and then you'll be issued a check, though I believe you can request it prior to that.

**Note that you may not even have to do this.** In the case where you'd like to take advantage of a low promotional rate for a "balance transfer" for more debt than you actually have, there are likely other options too. I've experienced all of these with different banks:

1. The bank simply doesn't care and will deposit the "transfer" directly into the bank account of your choosing, or send you a check. You typically tell them what you plan to do with the money, and maybe you do that, or maybe not.
2. The bank allows #1, but after the promotional APR expires (typically 9-18 months), the new APR becomes a typically higher cash advance rate instead of a purchase rate. Note this doesn't matter if you pay it off before the promotional window ends.
3. The bank only allows you to pay down existing debt, and will verify with the bank what the payoff amount is before sending the funds directly to that bank.

I've never experienced a bank that only does #3 and just takes your word for it regarding how much you owe.

**Side Note:** One time I was offered a rare 0% fee 0% APR for 18 months on a new CC, but it fell into category #3 where I needed existing debt to pay off, but I didn't have any, so I took out a big loan for 7 days and paid it off with the credit card. Then I dumped the cash into a high interest (I think it was 2.25% at the time) savings account that had a deposit bonus as well. I think I ended up profiting around $1K doing it (less after tax though).